# python 3.6 virtualenv - openblas crashes

Tags: python, numpy, lifelines

I'm running on Win7 64 bit, and have created a `virtualenv` with Python 3.6.

For a start, I've installed the latest numpy from `pypi` (`numpy-1.16.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64`).
However, even just importing numpy will result in `python.exe` crashing with:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   python.exe
Application Version:    3.6.150.1013
Application Timestamp:  585d65ae
Fault Module Name:  libopenblas.IPBC74C7KURV7CB2PKT5Z5FNR3SIBV4J.gfortran-win_amd64.
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 5c7579d9
Exception Code: c000001d
Exception Offset:   00000000010fecc1
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
Locale ID:  2057
Additional Information 1:   803c
Additional Information 2:   803cb5d48e343b732d1b1a4a3fec5baa
Additional Information 3:   c453
Additional Information 4:   c453864b3a6bedba5a0f03b0c7c20cb2
```

I've found an alternative package that seems to work for `numpy`: `numpy+mkl`.

But I have a similar issue with lifelines, which also crashes in `libopenblas`  and for which no alternative seems available.
So I'd ideally need to fix whatever is wrong with `openblas` on my machine, but I've found very little information about what could be going wrong here.

Has anyone seen this kind of issue before, or has an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you install [Anaconda Python](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), it comes [preinstalled with numpy and blas](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_win-64/).